# Identify the generated URL path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I've [this](https://code.damianoff.com/Laravelium/Sitemap) github package for my Laravel application, using composer, which creates sitemaps, but I am not able to understand where those sitemaps are rendered.

I had luck in finding the main sitemap after hitting /sitemap.xml URL location of my website, but I am unable to find other sitemaps like Google News sitemap one, which is supported by the package.

The responsible function seems this one, but my coding skills restrict me from understanding the rendered path:

```
/**
 * Returns document with all sitemap items from $items array
 *
 * @param string $format (options: xml, html, txt, ror-rss, ror-rdf, google-news)
 * @param string $style (path to custom xls style like '/styles/xsl/xml-sitemap.xsl')
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function render($format = 'xml', $style = null)
{
    // limit size of sitemap
    if ($this->model->getMaxSize() > 0 && count($this->model->getItems()) > $this->model->getMaxSize())
    {
        $this->model->limitSize($this->model->getMaxSize());
    }
    else if ('google-news' == $format && count($this->model->getItems()) > 1000)
    {
        $this->model->limitSize(1000);
    }
    else if ('google-news' != $format && count($this->model->getItems()) > 50000)
    {
        $this->model->limitSize();
    }

    $data = $this->generate($format, $style);

    if ('html' == $format)
    {
        return $data['content'];
    }

    return $this->response->make($data['content'], 200, $data['headers']);
}
```

Im generating my sitemap on HomeController, with this function:

```
    public function sitemap()
{
    $settings_general = Utils::getSettings("general");

    if ($settings_general->generate_sitemap == 1) {

        // create new sitemap object
        $sitemap = App::make("sitemap");

        // get all posts from db
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(600)->get();

        // add every post to the sitemap
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $sitemap->add(URL::to('/') . "/" . $post->slug, $post->updated_at, '1', 'hourly', null, $post->title);
        }

        $pages = DB::table('pages')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        // add every page to the sitemap
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $sitemap->add(URL::to('/') . "/" . $page->slug, $page->updated_at, '1', 'hourly', null, $page->title);
        }

        $categories = DB::table('categories')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        // add every category to the sitemap
        foreach ($categories as $category) {

            $sub_categories = SubCategories::where('parent_id', $category->id)->get();

            $sitemap->add(URL::to('/') . "/category/" . $category->slug, $category->updated_at, '1', 'hourly', null, $category->title);

            foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_category) {
                $sitemap->add(URL::to('/') . "/category/" . $category->slug . "/" . $sub_category->slug, $category->updated_at, '1', 'hourly', null, $category->title);
            }
        }

        return $sitemap->render('xml');
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on how you create your sitemap I guess. Can you edit your question and paste the code you use to generate a "Google News" sitemap? https://gitlab.com/Laravelium/Sitemap/-/wikis/Generate-sitemap

Comment: Looks like you're currently only generating an "xml" sitemap in `return $sitemap->render('xml');` According to the first piece of code you posted available formats are "_xml, html, txt, ror-rss, ror-rdf, google-news_". I guess you need to use `return $sitemap->render('google-news');` to render a google-news compliant sitemap